# InputMismatchException when parsing csv file with Scanner

Tags: java, file, csv, java.util.scanner, inputmismatchexception

I have been searching for a solution to this but basically whats happening is that I need to make a car database and import the values from a csv file. when I attempt to input the last cell in the csv file, the year, it returns 0 and an input mismatch...here is my code

```
public void readFile(String fileName) throws Exception {
    File f = new File(fileName);
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);
    sc.useDelimiter(",");

    while (sc.hasNext() && i < cars.length) {
        try {

            model = sc.next();
            sc.useDelimiter(",");
            make = sc.next();
            sc.useDelimiter(",");
            mpg = sc.nextDouble();
            sc.useDelimiter(",");
            weight = sc.nextInt();
            sc.useDelimiter(",");
            year = sc.nextInt();

        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("try again");
        }

        cars[i] = new Car(model, make, mpg, weight, year);

        // System.out.println(cars[i].toString());
        i++;
```

Output:

```
Welcome to the Car Database!
Enter the size of the array:
    5
Enter the name of the input file:
    cardb.csv
    try again
    try again
    try again
    try again
    try again
Enter make, mpg, weight, all, or quit:
    all
    Model:chevelle malibu Make:chevrolet mpg:18.0 weight:3504 year:0
    Model:70
    skylark 320 Make:buick mpg:15.0 weight:3693 year:0
    Model:70
    satellite Make:plymouth mpg:18.0 weight:3436 year:0
    Model:70
    rebel sst Make:amc mpg:16.0 weight:3433 year:0
    Model:70
    torino Make:ford mpg:17.0 weight:3449 year:0
```

Basically the year should say 70 and not 0 but it is reading it as the model on the next line...
here is the cardb.csv [file](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-f4e5NmM1-LWG5zY0V2MHN1WU0/edit).

Some of the inputs:

```
chevelle malibu,chevrolet,18,3504,70
skylark 320,buick,15,3693,70
satellite,plymouth,18,3436,70
rebel sst,amc,16,3433,70
torino,ford,17,3449,70
galaxie 500,ford,15,4341,70
impala,chevrolet,14,4354,70
fury iii,plymouth,14,4312,70
catalina,pontiac,14,4425,70
ambassador dpl,amc,15,3850,70
challenger se,dodge,15,3563,70
'cuda 340,plymouth,14,3609,70
```

Here is the exception,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at csc212hw04.CarDatabase.readFile(CarDatabase.java:58)
    at csc212hw04.Main.main(Main.java:47)
    C:\Users\Dan1\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
    BUILD FAILED (total time: 9 seconds)
```

Comment: Seriously; unless this is a homework assignment: do not code your own CSV parser. Getting that right is **harder** than you will ever think of. Turn to some 3rd party open source library for that.

Comment: this is actually a hw assignment

Comment: You need to include the stack trace in your question. You don't need to keep calling `userDelimiter(",")`. It won't change on you.

Comment: what is a stack trace?

Comment: It is the thing printed under the exception that shows where the exception was thrown from and the call stack that led to it.

Comment: So the next thing in the input at that point wasn't an integer. You need to call `sc.nextLine()` when you've finished with the current line, i.e. in this case at the bottom of the loop.

Comment: i tried that but i am still getting the same error

Comment: So you haven't fixed the input. Find the line in the file which causes the exception and fix it.

Comment: the input is correct but for some reason the scanner isnt picking it up